# How do you provide default props for nested shape in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way in React to provide default props to a nested array of items of a certain shape?

Given the example below, my first attempt can be seen, however this doesn't work as expected.

```
static propTypes = {
    heading: PT.string,
    items: PT.arrayOf(PT.shape({
        href: PT.string,
        label: PT.string,
    })).isRequired,
};

static defaultProps = {
    heading: 'this works',
    items: [{
        href: '/',
        label: ' - this does not - ',
    }],
};
```

In this example, I would expect the following:

```
// Given these props
const passedInProps = {
    items: [{ href: 'foo' }, { href: 'bar' }]
};

// Would resolve to:
const props = {
    heading: 'this works',
    items: [
      { href: 'foo', label: ' - this does not - ' },
      { href: 'bar', label: ' - this does not - ' },
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No. Default props are only shallowly merged.

However, one approach might be to have a Child component for each item. That way each Child component receives one object from the `item` array, and then the default props will be merged as you expect.

For example:

```
var Parent = React.createClass({

  propTypes: {
    heading: React.PropTypes.string,
    items: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.shape({
      href: React.PropTypes.string,
      label: React.PropTypes.string,
    })).isRequired
  },

  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
      heading: 'this works',
      items: [{
        href: '/',
        label: ' - this does not - ',
      }],
    };
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.item.map(function(item) {
          return <Child {...item} />
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }

});

var Child = React.createClass({

  propTypes: {
    href: React.PropTypes.string,
    label: React.PropTypes.string
  },

  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
      href: '/',
      label: ' - this does not - '
    };
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div />
        <p>href: {this.props.href}</p>
        <p>label: {this.props.label}
      </div>
    );
  }

});
```

Comment: Solid solution, but ... not so elegant. Any changes in React to allow a full merge of props since this was posted?

Comment: @RoyPrins Not as far as i know

Answer (score 0):

You could use a getter instead of calling `this.props`. You'd have to have *a lot* of items for it to be an expensive method. You could also modify `items` as I did below and then set it in the state, but React suggests against [deriving state from props](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html).

```javascript
class Foo extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    heading: PropTypes.string,
    items: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
      href: PropTypes.string,
      label: PropTypes.string,
    })).isRequired
  }

  static defaultLabel = ' - this does not - '
  static defaultHref = '/'

  get items() {
    return this.props.items.map((item) => ({
      href: item.href || this.defaultHref,
      label: item.label || this.defaultLabel,
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.items.map(({href, label}) => <a href={href}>{label}</a>)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```