# Can a default value be used in a proptype shape?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

Is it possible to define a type for an object's with a required key value pair and a default key value pair?

Example:

```js
const myComponent = (props) => {
  const {
    myObject: {
      someRequiredString,
      someNotRequiredString,
    }
  }
}

myComponent.propTypes = {
  myObject: PropTypes.shape({
    someRequiredString.string.isRequired,
  }).isRequired,
}

myComponent.defaultProps = {
  myObject: {
    someNotRequiredString: '',
  }
}
```

Comment: Usually required field didn't have a default value

Comment: True, but how about an object which has both a required and not required field? @VadimHulevich

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So if i understand you correct, you need non-required object bit if this object exist it's must have 2 required field, and maybe one non-required

So here we are:

```
componentForUser.propTypes = {
    myObject: PropTypes.shape({
        name:PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        secondName:PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        age:PropTypes.string,
    }),
}

componentForUser.defaultProps = {
    myObject: {
        name: 'defaultName',
        secondName: 'defaultSecondName',
        age:21
    }
}
```

In this case if User object is not required, instead of this you will get User with properties:

`myObject: {
        name: 'defaultName',
        secondName: 'defaultSecondName',
        age:21
    }`

But if from props you will get object User without name, you catch Warning about required name and secondName.

Comment: So the trick is to not set `.isRequired` on the object in the propTypes. Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this has changed since this question was asked, but you can't provide defaultProps for a nested value like this.

Comment: No, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38123498/how-do-you-provide-default-props-for-nested-shape-in-react), but there is a workaround explained.